# is it possible to record video using html5, in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, video, recording

Without using flash or silver light, is it possible to record video in all browsers (IE, Firefox, chrome, safari) with html 5

tried with getUserMedia(), which not support in ie8

Comment: Please specify what you mean by _all browsers_. Do you also want to target, for example, IE4?

Comment: IE 4 supports html 5?

Comment: IE8 has reached end of life with Microsoft and thus should not be in any general browser testing list. Consider it nonexistent when checking "all browsers"

Comment: @YasirPoongadan - no, ie4 doesn't support html5, and neither does ie8

Comment: @YasirPoongadan — Nothing (fully) supports HTML 5.

Comment: which version of IE support video recording, without flash and silver light ?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't use new features introduced in HTML 5 in browsers that predate it by years. IE8 has no video recording functionality that doesn't involve plugins.

Comment: which version of IE support video recording, without flash and silver light ?

Comment: Correct. It doesn't support that feature yet.

Comment: tanks Quentine, any other suggestion